# Show element on scroll (both up and down) - hide element when page is static (not scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to make a svg image of a computer mouse appear at the bottom of the viewport when user scrolls the page (both up and down scrolling). When the page is static (no scroll) I would like the element to be hidden. It is the same effect as the scrollbar on the right in the browser. Is it possible to apply this effect to a html element? Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the tour to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]`snippet editor

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by listening for the "scroll" event, `window.addEventListener('scroll', someFunction)`.

We can show the div by changing its display style from "none" to "block" `box.style.display = 'block'`.

And setting a timeout that, in five seconds, will call another function to hide the div again `setTimeout(hideBox, 5000)`.

You can find the definition and explanation for all of these functions in the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

I've also included a simple but working example:

```js
(function () {
  let timeoutHandle = 0;
  const box = document.getElementById("box");

  // add the scroll event
  window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    box.style.display = "block";
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    // call function to hide box after 5 seconds
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(hideBox, 5000);
  });

  // hides box by setting display to 'none'
  hideBox = () => {
    box.style.display = "none";
  };
})();
```

```css
#box {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  line-height: 95px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#box p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="top">
    <!-- hidden anchor --></a>
  <p> This is just some sample text.</p>
  <p> You should pay attention to the tiny box at the bottom right corner. It appears when you scroll.</p>
  <p> Now we add a very long image to make scrolling possible.</p>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/75/b7/8a/75b78ae86b6f81ed20f41f57e2a3a7f2.jpg">
</div>

<div id="box">
  <a href="#top">jump top</a>
</div>
```